# Version Agnostic SQL Server Script/Statement that detects existence of a specific database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Due to the packaged nature of the release, a SQL Server script (well more of a statement) needs to be created that can execute correctly on SQL Server 7.0 thru 2008 which can essentially achieve this:

```
if exists(select * from sys.databases where name = 'Blah')
```

Reasons this is difficult:

SQL 7 'sys.databases' is not valid

SQL 2008 'sysdatabases' is not valid

I stupidly parsed out the version number using serverproperty, to allow an IF depending on the version:

```
if (select CONVERT(int,replace(CONVERT(char(3),serverproperty ('productversion')),'.',''))) >= 80
```

Then discovered serverproperty does not exist under SQL 7.

Note that the SQL can be remote from the install, so no futzing around on the local machine - reg entries/file versions etc is of any use.

SQL Server error handling (especially 7.0) is poor, or maybe I don't understand it well enough to make it do a kind of try/catch.

I am now getting problem blindness to this, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Gareth

Comment: Why not just check if db_id('databasename') is null

Answer (score 1):

Try

USE database

and test @@ERROR.

> USE database
>   IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO ErrExit
>
> logic ...
>
> RETURN 0
>
> ErrExit:
>   RETURN 1

(or RAISERROR, or ...)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks G Mastros

This looks like it might yield a 100% solution.  It is available under SQL 7.

I need to complete and test, but at first glance I think it will fly.

Here's the draft code FYI.

```
create table #dwch_temp
(
name sysname
,db_size nvarchar(13)
,owner sysname
,dbid smallint
,created nvarchar(11)
,status nvarchar(600)
,compatibility_level tinyint
)
go



insert into #dwch_temp
exec sp_helpdb

if exists(select name from #dwch_temp where name = 'DWCHServer')


-- run the code


drop table #dwch_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a TRY... CATCH around a USE [DatabaseName].

Comment: He explicitly mentions that TRY ... CATCH isn't available in early versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a SQL 7 instance, but I encourage you to try:

```
sp_helpDB
```

I know this works on sql 2000 and sql 2005 to get a list of databases.  I suspect it works on SQL 7, too.

Answer (score 0):

sysdatabases is a remnant from the Sybase era and is still present in SQL 2008 (although deprecated). You can check for the existence of a database with a query like this:

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master..sysdatabases where name = 'Blah')